# Is there any way to distinguish chromedriver from chrome under Windows

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing Selenium testing and need to gather CPU and Memory info for the Browser:

```
Process.GetProcessesByName(TheBrowserName)
```

However, that will get CPU and Memory info from my normal chrome as well as Selenium chromedriver, because their name are both called "`CHROME`".

Hence the question, so that I can distinguish Selenium chromedriver from my normal chrome. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going to open any chrome windows manually during your testing, then you can create a `DateTime driverInitTime = DateTime.Now;` at the creation of your driver.

Once you run `Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");`, all instances created by Selenium will have a `StartTime` DateTime greater than `(>)` the driverInitTime.

```
DateTime driverInitTime = DateTime.Now;
Website website = new Website(new ChromeDriver("driver path if needed"));
Process[] chromeBrowsers = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
Process[] seleniumBrowsers = new Process[chromeBrowsers.Length];

int index = 0;
foreach(Process browser in chromeBrowsers) {
  if(browser.StartTime > driverInitTime)
  {
      seleniumBrowsers[index] = browser;
      index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thanks a lot @Fernando. You'll be a great asset to the SO site.